# LocalHost not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i write new code and then run it on the terminal, it doesn't show. I have to restart my computer for it to work. Why isn't this working?

I'm using VSC on a Chromebook (I know quite unusual).
I'm also using a node server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restart the server,

go to terminal and `ctrl c` and then restart

edit: also make sure you're saving?

Comment: haha common mistake, I still do that once in a while